# Enable durandal router nav properties after a certain event

Tags: durandal

I have multiple routes defined. One of the routes is my main route which is loaded on application startup and only this route has set `nav: true;` all other routes have set `nav: false;`

On the html page of the default route the user has to load the database data. Only when the database data is loaded all the other routes with `nav: false;` should be set to true.

```
 function databaseDataLoaded() {

        for (var i = 0; i < router.routes.length; i++) {
            router.routes[i].nav = true;
        }
    }
```

When the above method is called to render the hyperlinks of the navigation they are NOT rendered. Is the problem that my router.map function just takes common object literals and not knockout observables? Or is there a better way in the durandal architecture to handle scenarios like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is true for Durandal 1.X using the Sammy.js Router (I have yet to use the 2.0 router to test anything)**

The problem is that when you are mapping routes, the properties of the routes are not observables.  The router takes the routes you want to map and maps them, when the additional routes need to be mapped you need to go back and route them as well.

Example -

```
    router.map({
        url: 'home',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/home',
        name: 'Home',
        visible: true,
        settings: {}
    });
    return router.activate('home');
```

and after your data is loaded, then load the additional routes -

```
var newRoutes = [{
    url: 'other',
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/other',
    name: 'Other',
    visible: true,
    settings: {}
}, {
    url: 'about',
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/about',
    name: 'About',
    visible: true,
    settings: {}
}];
router.map(newRoutes );
```

**Edit**

If you are worried about where to put the routes simply move all the routes you want to load when data has been loaded into your config.js and only load the first route on app start up.  Example -

shell.js

```
function activate() {
    datacontext.loadData().then(loadAllRoutes);
    router.map({
        url: 'home',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/home',
        name: 'Home',
        visible: true,
        settings: {}
    });
    return router.activate('home');
}

function loadAllRoutes() {
    var routes = config.routes;
    router.map(routes);
}
```

**An alternative**

If you want to hide / show the routes based on different events but still load them all up at the same time just get a bit more creative with your NavBar.  The visibility toggle is still set to visible but you can use something like

```
<ul class="nav">
    // Show home route always
    <li>Home</li>
    <!-- ko foreach: visibleRoutes -->
    <li>(Put routes here)</li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

and create an observable in your shell that changes dataLoaded from false to true when data is finished loading.

```
var dataLoaded = ko.observable(false);
function activate() {
    datacontext.loadData().then(loadAllRoutes);
    var routes = config.routes;
    router.map(routes);
    return router.activate(config.startModule);
}

function loadAllRoutes() {
    dataLoaded(true);
}
```

Comment: This should work for durandal 2.0 too ? What I do not like is that the route configuration is now spread everywhere where my custom logic needs it instead of one router config.js file where everything is setup.

Comment: I have not used durandal 2.0.  And you still put your routes in a config you just load a single route first.  See the temphire breeze durandal example

Comment: I added two more examples to my answer of how you can still accomplish what you are trying to do using the tools available, the alternative would 100% accomplish what you are looking for.  The only thing that the visible property of the route is is a flag of whether it is visible in nav, it does not block it from being hit in the URL bar.

Comment: It shall not be allowed to hit the url in the address bar when those routes are not visible in the UI. So I guess I would have to go with your first suggestion, right? What do you think about the guardRoute function which could be used to prevent routing when certain application logic has not been fulfilled?

Comment: That would be best because routes with visible false can still be hit.

Comment: To which of my 2 questions is your answer related?

Comment: The first, you can certainly use guardroute as well but its going to be a lot more custom logic inside of there than just doing the first method I mentioned

Comment: Cool, if this was helpful to you consider flagging it as a correct answer to help others looking for similar answers find the same methods.

Comment: It works fine so far the user can not access any url before my custom logic runs to attach the new routes. But when they are attached the buttons to the routes are not visible. I guess I have to do something with the router.navigationModel(nav); which is an observablearray. But is this my job to extend the router.js that I can add a route to this observablearray? I do not think so... After I called my additional routes to be added I called this: router.buildNavigationModel(); inside debugging I have seen only my first route is added again and the additional routes were missing thus notVisible.

Comment: No it is not, if you use the method that I listed above it 100% works I use it in many projects.  Make sure you are setting the visibility on the new buttons that are being added to true and that you aren't filtering them out with logic anywhere.  If you aren't sure why they aren't showing up post your HTML for nav bar in your question and your viewmodel logic where you are mapping routes, or consider adding a fiddle with that information

Comment: ah now I understand you make the additinal routes visible when the custom logic adds the additional via router.map(...) ok i try.

Comment: I did it a different/better way: I set the nav property of my routes to true because then the get added to the             router.navigationModel(nav); observableArray and get automatically visible. So no reason to use directly the visible property, just understand how the routes work ;-)